# How do you turn a 3d character animation to 2d sprite sheets?

Tags: 3d, sprite, character-design

I made a 3D character with animation but now I need to make a 2D sprite sheet of this 3D character. Which program can I use for this and how is it created?

[image]

Comment: What format is your 3D character in? You could always take screen shots :P

Comment: Screen shots is not enough :) i use 3ds max i didnt find how to make izometric 2d sprite i am thinking to turn 3d character to 2d animations Can you help me for this?

Comment: You render a series of images and then reasemble the sprite sheet form those. Pretty basic 3ds max operation. Make a scene where teh camera moves to all your sprite position over an animation and render.

Comment: Blender is working too like 3dsmax and easier i learned. Thank you all